# access to a rest webservice in grails 4.0.1

Tags: rest, grails

I have a lot of successful rest accesses in grails 2.x.x
I simply coded

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.*
import grails.util.Holders
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray
```

and Classes JSONObject, JSONArray, RestBuilder, RestResponse where available for further use.

What are the corresponding imports in 4.0.1 and what jars resp. what lines in build.gradle are necessary?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the corresponding imports in 4.0.1 and what jars resp. what
>   lines in build.gradle are necessary?

Grails 4 offers better options than to interact with the classes you asked about but to answer the question as asked...

`org.grails.web.json.JSONObject` is in `grails-web-common-4.0.1.jar`.  Use `import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject`.

`org.grails.web.json.JSONArray` is in `grails-web-common-4.0.1.jar`.  Use `import org.grails.web.json.JSONArray`.

`grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder` is in `grails-datastore-rest-client-6.1.12.RELEASE.jar`.  Use `import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder`.

`grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse` is in `grails-datastore-rest-client-6.1.12.RELEASE.jar`.  Use `import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse`.

Depending on what other dependencies you may have in your project those may or may not be pulled in transitively so you may not need to add them to your `build.gradle` directly.  The most likely scenario is you won't need to add anything to pull in `grails-web-common-4.0.1.jar` but you probably will need to pull in `grails-datastore-rest-client-6.1.12.RELEASE.jar` which can be done by adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE"
```

If you want to pull in `grails-web-common` explicitly you could use the following:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-web-common:4.0.1"
```

If you are using the BOM correctly, you could simplify that with the following:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-web-common"
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: After Insert of compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE" in build.gradle I have a successful compile of my project but import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse are still red underlined by eclipse syntax checker. The json imports are compiled ok and have no red underlining though I not even included  compile "org.grails:grails-web-common:4.0.1" or compile "org.grails:grails-web-common" in my build gradle.

Comment: You will need to update the Eclipse project config to be aware of the new dependencies added to build.gradle.

Comment: How can I update eclipse project config ? Is there a config file or something in the menues ? I just know the refresh button.

Comment: But despite from this. I have huge problems in generating views and controllers via generate-all for my domain classes e.g. I get:  'Groovy:No implementations possible for method 'org.strotmann.fragdening.Experte get(java.io.Serializable)'. Please use an abstract class  instead and provide an implementation'  in generated interface ExperteService.' In addition in the respective generated create view I get a buggy line '<li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>' where <li> tag is not closed.

Comment: After all these problems I have decided to make a fallback to stable grails 2.4.4

Comment: to avoid any confusions, fallback to stable 2.4.4 does not intend 4.0.1 as unstable. My fallback to 2.4.4 is intended as a return to a system I'm familiar with.